# Get results of fast-memoize

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using [fast-memoize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fast-memoize) with `Immutable JS` and `React` .
Currently, I am memorizing a variable like this

```
function stateToProps(state) {
    const memoMe = memoize(state.getIn(...);
    console.log(memoMe);
    return {
        headline: state.getIn(...),
        memoMe: memoMe,
    };
}
```

However, the log of `memoMe` gives me this

```
ƒ monadic (fn, cache, serializer, arg) {
  var cacheKey = isPrimitive(arg) ? arg : serializer(arg)

  var computedValue = cache.get(cacheKey)
  if (typeof computedValue === 'undefined') {
    computedV…
```

How do I access the memorized object?

Answer (score 0):

library takes a function as a parameter, not the value. It returns a new function which then returns the cached values if same arguments are passed to it. So you would do something like this,

```
function stateToProps(state) {
    const memoizeFn = memoize(state.getIn);
    //memoizeFn is a function which will return cached result if arguments are repeated

    return {
        //first call to memoizeFn, memoizeFn will compute result using state.getIn
        headline: memoizeFn([a,b]),
        //second call with same arguments, memoizeFn will return cached results
        memoMe: memoizeFn([a, b]),
    };
}
```

Comment: Ah, so lets say `const memoizeFn = memoize(state.getIn(['a', 'b'])).toJS()` and then I simplay call the function with the same arguments as before, so `return {headline: memoizeFn(state.getIn(['a', 'b'])),};`?

Comment: @Stophface `state.getIn(['a', 'b'])` is the value, not the function right? You have to pass a function to `memoize ` . See the updated comments.

Comment: Hm, that gives me an `undefined` when I try to access `memoMe: memoizeFn([a, b])` like this.